# How to exclude programmatically a generated Gradle task?

Tags: gradle

Task `task0` depends on `task1` which is generated by a rule.

A `build.gradle` with:

```
project.task0.dependsOn -= task1
```

fails since `task1` hasn't yet been generated.

Using `gradle.taskGraph.whenReady` also doesn't work since it's too late to modify the task graph (although this can be used to disable tasks).

How can generated tasks be removed from a task's dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do it with something like:

```
project.gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.task0.dependsOn -= "task1"
}
```

or:

```
project.gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.task0.dependsOn -= tasks.task1
}
```

or simply:

```
project.gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.task0.dependsOn = []
}
```

I found it helpful to output the dependencies before/after the change, to make sure it was having the desired effect:

```
project.gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.xyz.dependsOn.forEach {
        println("before: " + it + " (type " + it.getClass() + ")")
    }
    // modify tasks.xyz.dependsOn in some way
    tasks.xyz.dependsOn.forEach {
        println("after: " + it + " (type " + it.getClass() + ")")
    }
}
```